# unresolved error of AbstractBaseUser from the Django example

Tags: python, django

When I read the Django document: [customize user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/)

the example did not give the import `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
```

I don't know how to import it, so there is unresolved error in my project.

---

[image]

---

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AbstractBaseUser` in in the auth.models, you can import like bellow:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import
```